# Final non-polymorphic class in C++11

Tags: c++11, polymorphism, overriding, final

I just one to make sure no one will derive from my non-polymorphic class, so I used following syntax:

```
class Foo final
{
    Foo();
    ~Foo(); // not virtual

    void bar();
};
```

In *The C++ programming language* I read that `final` can be used together with `override` for classes containing virtual member functions. I tried my code sample in VS 2013 and it compiles without any warning.

Is it allowed to use keyword `final` for non-polymorphic classes to prevent derivation from the class ? Does the keyword `override` make sense with non-polymorphic classes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ grammar allows `final` to appear in two different places. One is a *class-virt-specifier* which can appear after the class name in a class declaration, which is how you've used it. Despite the name, using a *class-virt-specifer* has nothing to do with virtual functions and is allowed in non-polymorphic classes.

The other place it can be used is a *virt-specifier* on a member function. If present, a *virt-specifer* sequence consists of one or both of `final` and `override`, but is only allowed on virtual functions (9.2 [class.mem] "A *virt-specifier-seq* shall contain at most one of each *virt-specifier*. A *virt-specifier-seq* shall appear only in the declaration of a virtual member function (10.3)."). So `override` can only be used on virtual functions, so cannot be used in non-polymorphic types.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is allowed even if your class is not virtual:

from cppreference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final

> When used in a class definition, final specifies that this class may
>   not appear in the base-specifier-list of another class definition (in
>   other words, cannot be derived from).

The override keyword on the other hand makes no sense for non polymorphic classes.